# Android database is overlapping

Tags: android

I am new in android. I am reading the database correctly and my application is working fine but the problem is when reading from database the contents in some page are overlapping with one another. At first I thought its problem with my layout and I crosschecked with huge data its working properly where as now its giving now.

![enter image description here][1]
Can anybody please tell me whats wrong where shall I correct it.
[I am sorry I tried that I tried to post the screenshots but stackoverflow is not allowing me saying 10 reputation ]

Here is the code of the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#2a2a2a"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
<!-- Child linear layout with horizontal orientation -->
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#2a2a2a"
              android:layout_marginTop="25dip">



    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView07"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView09"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

.........................................................................................
Thank you very much for your time...........

Comment: Please post the link to the screenshot so someone else can embed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have set "match_parent" for all your TextView layout_height's. Change them to "wrap_content" and try again.